# Create "scam" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We've had a [a lot of questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+scam) about potential job scams, but there isn't yet a tag for it. I thought it would be good to go back and add a [scam](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scam) tag to all of the old questions, but I also don't want to go resurrecting a bunch of old questions without mod input. The mods probably also have a way of doing it all automatically rather than slogging through it by hand. Would anyone else be in favor of going back and adding a tag to all of these questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would anyone else be in favor of going back and adding a tag to all of
>   these questions?

No.

I'd be concerned about all the "is this a scam?" questions that would likely follow.

Comment: Agreed. Money spends too much time on "of course it's  a scam". I'd rather encourage folks to learn that if they have doubts about a situation that is probably sufficient reason to walk away from it.

Comment: We'd never see the end of posts like that, agreed.  Plus, it also amounts to giving legal advice.  We could add something to the community wikki to show SIGNS of a scam

Comment: A canonical answer about "how check if a Job offer is serious" would be enough for this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is why I asked before doing anything!

Comment: @keshlam if you want to encourage folks to learn it it seems necessary they be allowed to ask about it here.